# Javascript - Convert date string to US date format

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have a string named regdate and the value is 16-4-2017 00:00:00

Now I have been trying for a few hours to convert this string to this kind of format: 4/16/2017 12:00:00 AM

I know this question could be duplicated but I have been looking on the internet for hours now.

Comment: Are there really three `0`s in a row?

Comment: sorry typing mistake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now finished!!

```js
var time = "16-4-2017 13:00:00";
var date = time.split(' ')[0].split('-'); //now date is ['16', '4', '2017'];
time = time.split(' ')[1].split(':'); //now time is ['13', 00', 00']
var dateFull = new Date(date[2], date[1], date[0], time[0], time[1], time[2]);
var dateString = (dateFull.getMonth()) + dateFull.toString().substring(0, dateFull.toString().indexOf('G')).substring(7).replace(' ', '/').replace(' ', '/');
if (dateFull.getHours() > 12) dateString = dateString.replace(dateFull.getHours(), dateFull.getHours() - 12) + 'PM';
else if (dateFull.getHours() == 12) dateString += 'PM';
else dateString += 'AM';
console.log(dateString);
```

Comment: Also doing something but not correct. returns: Tue May 16 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 it should be 16/4/2017 12:00:00 AM, Dont get me wrong I would prefer this as working solution as I would not be required to use third party scripts

Comment: still returns Tue May 16 2017 00:00:00

Comment: now it has May/16/2017 00:00:00 Almost done, it should be: 
16/4/2017 12:00:00 AM but I am wondering if it is even possible to do so

Comment: No if you add AM at the ned it will always be AM. What I just edited makes it have AM or PM correctly instead of always AM like what you did.

Answer (score 4):

**Method 1 - Parse with regular expression, format output with toLocaleString**

In this code snippet, the `string.match` method is used to parse the date string. A date object is then created with the date parts, and `toLocaleString("en-US")` is used to get the US date format:

```js
function convertDate(regdate) {
  var m = regdate.match(/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)\s+(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/);
  var date = new Date(m[3], m[2] - 1, m[1], m[4], m[5], m[6]);
  return date.toLocaleString("en-US");
}
```

```html
Date: <input id="txtDate" type="text" value="16-4-2017 00:00:00" />
<button onclick="console.log(convertDate(document.getElementById('txtDate').value))">Convert</button>
```

**Method 2 - Parse and replace with regular expression**

In the second code snippet, the `string.replace` method is used to modify the date string: a regular expression parses the original date string, and a replacement function recombines the various parts:

```js
function convertDate(regdate) {
  return regdate.replace(/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)\s+(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/,
    function(m, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6) {
      var hour24 = parseInt(v4, 10);
      var hour12 = hour24 % 12 || 12;
      var ampm = hour24 < 12 ? "AM" : "PM";
      return `${v2}/${v1}/${v3} ${hour12}:${v5}:${v6} ${ampm}`;
    });
}
```

```html
Date: <input id="txtDate" type="text" value="16-4-2017 00:00:00" />
<button onclick="console.log(convertDate(document.getElementById('txtDate').value))">Convert</button>
```

**Method 3 - Parse with datejs library, format output with toLocaleString**

If you don't mind using an external library, you can convert the string to a date with [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) and use `date.toLocaleString("en-US")` to format the output:

```js
var date = Date.parse("16-4-2017 00:00:00");
console.log(date.toLocaleString("en-US"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datejs/1.0/date.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Would it work if I would do var date = new date(regdate);
I parse the regdate string from selected customers in a grid. Can't really hard code them like this I guess

Comment: @MiaSan No it wouldn't work. `new Date(string)` only accepts certain formats and not even that reliable cross-browser.

Comment: @MiaSan - I added a link to the datejs library for the parsing of the date string.

Comment: You sir, are a wizard, Thanks alot!

Comment: I added two methods that use regular expressions, if you prefer to avoid external libraries.

Comment: You were doing well until `Date.parse("16-4-2017 00:00:00")`, which produces `NaN` in Safari. Also, `Date.parse` returns a number (a time value), not a Date, so `date.toLocaleString()` will throw an error. Don't parse strings with the Date.parse or the Date constructor.

Comment: @RobG - The `Date.parse` used in method 3 is the one provided by datejs. When I try it in Safari (on my iPad), it works. I saw that datejs also provides versions for specific cultures but I haven't found a CDN for them. My code snippet uses the "default" one.

Comment: I missed the "with Date.js" part. But it's still a bad idea to pass a string to a parser and not tell it the format, or to rely on *toLocaleString* without passing any options other than a language tag.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var q = new Date(Date.parse('2017-4-16 00:00:00'));
console.log(q.toLocaleDateString()+q.toLocaleTimeString());
```

This should help. But check the input format of the date. The format you posted will always give you `NaN`

Comment: `new Date(Date.parse('2017-4-16 00:00:00'))` is **identical** to `new Date('2017-4-16 00:00:00')`. Never parse strings with the *Date* constructor (or *Date.parse*, they are equivalent for parsing). *toLocaleDateString* is entirely implementation dependent and may not respect the user system settings, so the format it returns can be anything and may well not be the OP's required US format.

Answer (score 0):

Just another example, but a little more concise:

```js
// Reformat 16-4-2017 00:00:00 to 4/16/2017 12:00:00 AM
function reformatString(s) {
  var b = s.split(' ');
  var d = b[0].replace(/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/,'$2/$1/$3');
  var t = b[1].split(':');
  return d + ' ' + (t[0]%12 || 12) + ':' + t[1] + ':' + t[2] + (t[0] < 12? ' AM' : ' PM');
}

console.log(reformatString('16-4-2017 00:00:00'));
```

However, formatting a string in US format with just digits is very ambiguous. Far better to use an unambiguous format, such as using the month name rather than number, e.g. April 16, 2017 12:00:00 AM

Answer (score 0):

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">

  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="123" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="123" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="123" roles="role1"/>
  <user username="souvik" password="xyz123" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status" />
</tomcat-users>
```